# MySQL sub-queries using WHERE and HAVING clauses

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause, having-clause

Create three queries using tables Employee_T and hoursWorked_T.

1. Returns a single column and single row in the outer query's WHERE clause
2. Returns a single column and single row in the outer query's HAVING clause
3. Returns a multi-column table in the outer-query's FROM clause

#### MySQL tables

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee_T
  (
     empName VARCHAR(25)),
     empNo INT,
     Primary Key(empName)
  );

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hoursWorked_T
  (
   empName VARCHAR(20),
   plannedHours INT,
   actualHours INT,
   Foreign Key(empName)
  );
```

Comment: Have you tried any query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] clause soon.  Your question is rather under-specified.  What queries are appropriate?  What sample data do you have?  What is the range of employee numbers, for example?  The three queries are so vague it is not at all clear what might be desired.